# Forking and piping processes in a loop in Linux C

Tags: c, fork, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main() 
{  
  int pfd[2];  
  int status,i;  
  char input[1024];
  int rfds[n]; //Hold the file IDs of each pipe fd[0]
  int wfds[n]; //Holds the file IDs of each pipe fd[1]
  int pids[n]; //Holds the list of child process IDs


  while(fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin)){   
    for (i=0;i<6;i++){
      if(pipe(pfd) < 0) 
    {  
      printf("Failed to create pipe!\n");  
      return 1;  
    }
      //Store the pipe ID
      rfds[i] = pfd[0];
      wfds[i] = pfd[1];
      if((pids[i] = fork())<0){
    printf("Failed to fork!\n");  
    return 1;  
      }  
      if (pids[i]==0) {    
    close(wfds[i]);
    if(read(rfds[i],input,strlen(input)) > 0)  
      {  
        printf("process #%d (%d) relaying message:%s",i,getpid(),input);
      }
    close(rfds[i]);
    }  
      else  
    {   
      close(rfds[i]);
      if((write(wfds[i], input, strlen(input))) ==-1)  
        {  
          printf("Failed to write!\n");
          return 1;
        }  
        close(wfds[i]);
        wait(&status);  
    }
    } 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I code this to transmits messages from process to process. but i want to make the last process connect to the first process.
i.e., what it output is like

```
process #0 (47652) sending message: MD
process #1 (47653) relaying message: MD
process #2 (47654) relaying message: MD
process #3 (47655) relaying message: MD
process #4 (47656) relaying message: MD
process #5 (47657) relaying message: MD
process #6 (47658) relaying message: MD
```

What i need is the last process is done in the process with process id 47651 rather than 47658

Comment: Would appreciate it if you spent a little time cleaning up your code before submitting.

Comment: You have to create a pipe before the first fork, this is the end pipe to which the last process can connect to the first. That way you can achieve round robin communication. Doest that make sense?

Comment: Which part is unclear to you?

Comment: @Montaldo Do you mean i need to write the first or the last process separately?

Comment: @arjenz exactly same?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create one end pipe before you start the forking. Because this is needed for the last process to connect to the first.

I have some code which you can create children with.

```
void createChildren(int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int end_pipe[2];        
    int incomming[2];
    int outgoing[2];

    /* create the end pipe */
    pipe(end_pipe);

    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
    {
        pipe(outgoing);

        /* parent process */
        if (fork() != 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        /* incomming pipe of the child is the outgoing of the parent */
        incomming[0] = outgoing[0];
        incomming[1] = outgoing[1];     
    }

    /**
     * If master then the incomming pipe is the end pipe. Glue the end to the beginning
     */
    if (i == 0)
    {
        incomming[0] = end_pipe[0];
        incomming[1] = end_pipe[1];
    }   

    /**
     * If master then the ougoing pipe is the end pipe. Glue the end to the beginning
     * Initial write to the ring
     */
    if (i == size - 1)
    {
        int buffer = 0;

        outgoing[0] = end_pipe[0];
        outgoing[1] = end_pipe[1];

        write(outgoing[1], &buffer, sizeof(int));
    }

    runClient(i, size, incomming, outgoing);
}
```

Comment: What is incomming, end_pipe and outgoing?

Comment: That are the pipes each process uses to communicate. If you use and array for let's say 6 processes and you do an amount of forks your array is going to be duplicated six times causing a lot of overhead if you don't close all the not used pipes. If you only create 2 pipes per process. Three in this case because you need an end pipe, it saves you a lot of overhead

Comment: So what you do is you create two pipes. One for incomming and on for outgoing connections. Like you did. Every new process uses these. But you need one more, because that is your problem. How to connect the first and the last process. Well if you want to do that you have to create a pipe in the first process that is there for teh last process to connect to. I called this end_pipe you can name it anything you want

Comment: I can't see why you use two fds for incomming and also two for outgoing.

Comment: `int cfd[2];pipe(cfd);if (i==0){
rfds[i] = cfd[0];
wfds[i] = cfd[1];
} 
if (i==n-1){
rfds[i] = cfd[0];
wfds[i] = cfd[1];
}`Why this doesn't work too?

Comment: You only create a fds for the outgoing. the incomming if used to keep track of who is getting what. If you want to stick to the array solution that is fine, the point is that you generate ALOT of overhead. Imagne having 6 processes. so every fork you are creating 12 new fds and you have to close everything that you don't use. But that makes the code far more complicated. since process a has to talk with process b and b with c, you need a both incomming and outgoing. (Excuse my english on incomming -.-). You have to set the previous, the incomming of the child to the outgoing of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just create n pipes (you could use an array), where n is the number of processes. Then every time write to the pipe of the next one and read from you own pipe. At the end of the loop, just use a modulo to stay within the array of pipes.

Does this help? I could give you some code, but it should not be too hard.